# Overload an overridden, inherited method

Tags: java, class, inheritance, overriding

Say I have my class A and class B inherits from A. I want to override the method `public void print()` which should work just fine.

But is it possible to overload `public void print()` in B, but with a parameter this time without declaring the method in class A?

```
abstract class A {
    String name;
    public void print();
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello"); // Works just fine
    }

    public void print(String s) {
        System.out.println("Hello" + s); // Doesn't work when calling it, as it must be declared in A
    }
}
```

Comment: No. That's called overloading and has nothing to do with inheritance. How would it work anyway, overriding a parameterless method with one that requires a parameter?

Comment: Why do you want to override a method who don't exists in super? Just simply declare it. What you want to do is named overloading, same name, different parameters.

Comment: @Gendarme You're right , sorry. Overloading is what I meant. But is it possible to Overload the method print() without declaring it print(string s) in A?

Comment: It is possible to overload print(), you already done that. You call it like `B bb = new B();` -> `bb.print("text");`

Comment: @KunLun I see, thank you. I was trying to do it with: `A obj = new B();` and then obj.print("there").

Comment: @Mugen1994 this will not work - to call it on a an object declared as `A obj = new B();` it must be declared in the class `A`

Comment: to done that, you need to do `((B)obj).print("there");`. Because `A obj = new B()` mean your object type will be `A` with an instance of `B` and you need to tell compiler to try to convert it to `B` with cast `(B)obj`. P.S.: I'm not very good to explain this. If someone think I was wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to overload public void print() in B with a parameter without declaring the method in class A. But you have to define abstract class as:

```
abstract class A
{
String name;
public abstract void print();
}
```

An abstract class can have abstract method as well as normal method also. When You are declaring normal method then you have to give implementation also for that method. Otherwise you have to declare that method with abstract keyword (Otherwise You will get compilation error) i.e. No need to give implementation. In your case you have to declare printf() method with abstract keyword as mention above. When you extend class A then in class B you have to provide the implementation for printf() method which is abstract in class A , which is known as Method Overriding. Apart from that you can define printf() method with any parameter, which is known as Method Overloading. But You have to access both the methods using class B object only because abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but can only be inherited. Please refer below code :

```
abstract class A
{
String name;
public abstract void print();
}
class B extends A
{
@Override
public void print(){
System.out.println("Hello");
}
//Overloaded method with String parameter
public void print(String s){
System.out.println("Hello" + s);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
new B().print();//calling inherited method with class B object
new B().print("Bishal");//calling overloaded method with class B object
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is perfectly fine. It is considered overloading a method, which is a common practice in java. You would only need to declare the `print()` method in class A abstract like:

```
public abstract class A 
{
String name;
public abstract void print();
}
```

Comment: It seems you did not understand the question. This doesn't answer it.